# Angularjs and Rails: html5mode causes infinite page loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have following configuration in app.js:

```
$routeProvider.when('/signs/new', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/NewSign.html',
  controller:  'EditSignController'
});
$routeProvider.when('/signs', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/SignList.html',
  controller: 'SignListController'
});
$routeProvider.when('/signs/:signId', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/SignDetails.html',
  controller: 'SignController'
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/signs'});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I use `thin` webserver.

routes.rb:

```
Pdd::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :signs

  root to: "home#index"
  get '*path' => "home#index"

end
```

application_controller.rb

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery

      before_filter :intercept_html_requests
      after_filter :set_csrf_cookie_for_ng

      def set_csrf_cookie_for_ng
        cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
      end


      protected

      def verified_request?
        super || form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN']
      end

      private

      def intercept_html_requests
        render('home/index') if request.format == Mime::HTML
      end

    end
```

Route `/signs` works good, but acessing `/signs/new` or `signs/1` forces `thin` to reload assets again and again, so page can not be loaded at all and I can only kill the tab in browser. What am I doing wrong?